# How to get Visual Studio to use selected text in a comment for goto definition

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio, you can select a variable or type and use the goto definition or declaration function to get to the definition or declaration. But if the variable or type is in a comment, visual studio can't find the definition. ex: /* variable */. If you select 'variable', it appears visual studio searches for "/* variable */" instead of "variable", and can't find it. Is there a way to adjust the text used for the search to just the selected text? My work around it to paste the text to some area outside of a comment, and do the 'goto definition' there, but it seems this should not be necessary.